# How do I use one .env as the source of truth

Tags: linux, windows, cross-platform, posix, .env

I am creating a build system for development purposes for the FreeCAD application. Repo is [here](https://github.com/FruitfulSystems/FreeCAD-Dev#v1.0) if you want to get a better scope of what I'm talking about.

Essentially the folder structure is:

```
(Main)
  (Linux)
    (Ubuntu)
      ubuntu.sh
      ubuntu.Dockerfile
    (Fedora)
      fedora.sh
      fedora.Dockerfile
  (Windows)
  (Mac)
  .env
```

What I want to do is use the env variables in .env as a central source of truth for all the build scripts in the tree. But I don't want to have to explicitly define the path of the .env inside the files, absolute or relative paths, as I'm still iterating and I don't want to update all the files if I rearrange the tree. Alternatively, I don't want to put independent .env's in all the child dirs for the same reason (unless they auto update somehow)

**My question is as follows:**

**How do I just explicitly define the "local" path of .env in each script, Dockerfile, etc but only have to modify one top level .env file to auto-update an evolving tree. In a cross platform way**

Some things I thought through:

Windows uses "hard links" which are equivalent but non compatible with POSIX hardlinks. I thought about creating `windows.env` and `posix.env` in each child dir that point to the same main .env. But most config files can only take one .env path argument.

I thought about writing a script that will update all the .env's when run (would rather not have to), or alternatively, I will accept an answer that uses some dotenv tooling to accomplish the same goal as long as it's cross-platform, and runs locally. I'm just not super familiar with those toolings. I would prefer the tooling or script run as a service and not have to be run everytime in order to update the files.

IF I'm using Git AND only referring to shell scripts, then a command at the top of the script such as  `. /$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/.env` works well but has major limitations for use with dockerfiles and other yml based file types.

I currently use a `run.sh` file at the top level dir that sources the .env and then calls the other files within it. This seems to be the most used pattern I see in other repos. But this means I need to have two files run.sh and run.pwsh which just seems extranuous and hacky to add extras files that are basically one liners.

Comment: A couple of ideas: (1) `run.py` not `run.sh`. (2) actually a script that updates all the `.env`s doesn't sound like it would work. (3) like autotools, you can have the build system generate the scripts, Dockerfiles, etc., from templates, and plug the correct values.

Comment: @root 1) True that fixes that part.

Comment: 2) I said build system, but that might me causing confusion, I just don't know what else to call it. Hopefully a little clearer here, This would not be "building" as in preperation for compilation. That part is  handled already by the FreeCAD community. What this would be doing is pulling the tar or source code for a FreeCAD version and mounting it in to docker containers  with the build dependencies built into them (initially, but the plan would be to expand to virtual machines as an option)

Comment: continued 2) as an example, in the top level .env I would specify which version I want to spin up (for nightly editing, or for fixing a bug in an earlier version) Then I would run a `docker compose up in the directory of the platform I want to spin it up in.

Comment: Just to clarify the purpose of this system. It's for making development on multiple versions of FreeCAD in one machine easier and faster. 

This is a simple example, I might want to add vars that would change dependency versions too in the container builds. My question is really just a beginning point for what I'm trying to accomplish here and I'll probably end up writing a script that takes user input and automatically does all this.

Comment: Is it just docker? It seems to me that question isn't docker-specific, could be about dockerfiles, makefiles, etc.. It sounds like you're looking for a generic, cross-format, cross-platform way to make this work. If that's indeed the case, than GNU's autotools model is the best I can think of. there's also [envsubst](https://linux.die.net/man/1/envsubst), but IMO there's going to be a lot of coding you'll have to do around it.

Comment: At the moment, but eventually it would include VM's too. In my repo I will not be targeting direct host machines as it's difficult managing dependency conflicts so makefiles not so much here though I could see anaconda or nix management systems in the future.You are right about the question itself though. I'm currently looking at autotools, as I'm not too familiar. I come from a web background so building and compiling in general are newer concepts to me.

Comment: I don't know autotools myself very well, so I don't know if it's worth your time, I was mainly referring to its model - using templates and generating build instructions (e.g. generate `Dockerfile` from `Dockerfile.template`. I've done something similar for `docker-compose.yml`, but for a different use case.